# Android app project in eclipse-ERROR

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a new project in eclipse . And I am getting the following error in res->values->styles.xml file -

"Error retrieving parent for item .No resource found that matches the name Theme.AppCompat.Light"

Any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because that theme isn't present in your project. Go to **res->values->styles.xml** and remove `Theme.AppCompat.Light`, this should solve the error.

Comment: What was the problem?? I did'nt even type anything . Then why this error?

Comment: parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" ...I removed this line and then there was no error.

Comment: @Abhimanyu And you were able to run your code? If yes then kindly accept it as an answer.

Comment: problem occured because eclipse is no longer supported for android development so when a project is created it uses latest AppCompact library which is not present, you should try moving to Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project -> properties -> android -> in the library section , click on add and add appcompat . This solved my problem .